# API contents display using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

hello friends i developed an API for FAQ page like below

[image]

I want to display selection:label and selection:key following is my angular code but i am unable to get output

[image]

tell me friends how to call inner API contents using angularjs? any syntax modification in angular code ??

Comment: Share ur javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your `div ng-repeat`

```
<div>{{ a.items['selection:key'] }}</div>
<div>{{ a.items['selection:label'] }}</div>
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept it. That's how it works here in SO.